# mayavi: how to zoom in very very close (change near clipping distance)

Tags: python, mayavi

I'm trying to visualize a point on the surface of the earth using the mlab interface to mayavi.  The main problem is that the earth is big, but I want to be able to zoom in to see a very small region of it.

It appears that using the scrollwheel in a mayavi window changes the distance of the camera from its focal point.  If I focus on the point I'm interested in and zoom in, eventually the camera's distance to the focal point is smaller than the near clipping distance, and I can't see the point of interest any more.

I can programmatically set the near clipping point of the camera like so:

```
eng = mlab.get_engine() 
scene = eng.scenes[0].scene 
cam = scene.camera
scene.camera.clipping_range = [10000, 100000]
```

and that properly shows the point I want to see, but if I do ANYTHING with the mouse (rotate the view by dragging, move the scrollwheel), the clipping plane gets reset and I can't see anything.  This halfway defeats the purpose of the mayavi window.

**The question:  How can I make this example work so that I can see the point i'm drawing ( the glyph is 1 meter across) and still interact with the window?**

Here is my code (for readability, the drawSphere function is below):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import r_, c_, pi
from mayavi import mlab

rE  = 6378137 #radius of the earth, in meters
drawSphere(r=rE)
pointAEcef = c_[-2252280.7, -5867391.7,  1100769.5]
mlab.points3d(pointAEcef[:,0],pointAEcef[:,1],pointAEcef[:,2],
    color=(0.0,0.0,1.0),scale_factor=1.0
    )

mlab.view(
          azimuth=-110.09214289721747,
          elevation=102.86270612105356,
          distance=80.0,
          focalpoint=pointAEcef[0,:],
          )
eng = mlab.get_engine()
scene = eng.scenes[0].scene
cam = scene.camera
scene.camera.clipping_range = [50, 27e6]
scene.render()

mlab.show()
```

Here is the drawSphere function:

```
def drawSphere(r=1,fig=None):
    """
    Draw a sphere of the given radius in the given figure
    """
    r = float(r)
    # Create a sphere
    pi = np.pi
    cos = np.cos
    sin = np.sin
    phi, theta = np.mgrid[0:pi:101j, 0:2*pi:101j]

    x = r*sin(phi)*cos(theta)
    y = r*sin(phi)*sin(theta)
    z = r*cos(phi)

    if fig is not None:
        fig = mlab.figure(fig)
    else:
        fig = mlab.gcf()

    colorsphere=mlab.mesh(x,y,z,
                          figure=fig,
                          color=(0,0,1),
                          opacity=0.1,
                          )
    grid = mlab.mesh(x,y,z,
                     figure=fig,
                     mask_points=100,
                     color=(1,0,0),
                     representation="wireframe",
                     opacity=0.1,
                     )

    xaxis = mlab.quiver3d(0,0,0,1.5*r,0,0,color=(1,0,0),scale_mode='none',scale_factor=r);
    yaxis = mlab.quiver3d(0,0,0,0,1.5*r,0,color=(0,1,0),scale_mode='none',scale_factor=r);
    zaxis = mlab.quiver3d(0,0,0,0,0,1.5*r,color=(0,0,1),scale_mode='none',scale_factor=r);
    #mlab.view(azimuth=0,elevation=90,distance=1.1,focalpoint=(0,0,0));
    #mlab.roll(30);
    #cam = fig.scene.camera;       
    return (colorsphere,grid,xaxis,yaxis,zaxis)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want the center of rotation to be closer to the surface of the sphere. I believe that in most VTK environments, the center of rotation is the focal point. I'm not sure if there are keystrokes or mouse gestures to change this, but I'm pretty sure that "zooming" in mayavi (e.g., using the scroll wheel) is actually dollying (unless you are in parallel projection mode), so you are moving both the camera and the focal point.

You might want to try finding the [camera.SetDistance](http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/5.2/html/a00154.html#98f6dd235b4ecf71841ca32fcd94635d) function, and setting the distance to the focal point to be 1 or 2 meters. In TVTK, this would be something like scene.camera.distance = 2  ... or, there's a good chance that Mayavi has a menu which exposes this option.

Good luck!

Comment: AttributeError: 'OpenGLCamera' object has no attribute 'SetDistance'